# Using xtreg with unique identifier that includes letters

Tags: panel, stata

I am trying to run a regression with my panel dataset.

I want to account for state fixed effects, and attempting to work with a bit of a strange identifier.

My unit of analysis is the utility in the state, for which I have created a composite unique identifier comprising of utility_id and state.

My data thus looks as follows:

```
unique_id     ownership   amiratio   popd
10570AL       REC         .45        3430
4032CA        IOU         .85        4350
```

However, `xtset` does not like letters in the identifiers.

My intended regression looks like the one below:

```
xtreg amiratio ownership ownership#popd, fe vce(cluster i.state)
```

How can I get my unique ID into the right form to run this regression?

Answer (score 1):

The `encode` command can be used for this purpose:

```
clear
input str10 unique_id str3 ownership amiratio popd
10570AL REC .45 3430
4032CA IOU .85 4350
end

encode unique_id, generate(wanted)
```

This converts a string variable to numeric with value labels matching the strings:

```
list unique_id wanted, abbreviate(10)

     +---------------------+
     | unique_id    wanted |
     |---------------------|
  1. |   10570AL   10570AL |
  2. |    4032CA    4032CA |
     +---------------------+

list unique_id wanted, abbreviate(10) nolabel

     +--------------------+
     | unique_id   wanted |
     |--------------------|
  1. |   10570AL        1 |
  2. |    4032CA        2 |
     +--------------------+
```

Using `xtset` with `wanted` will work in contrast with `unique_id`:

```
xtset unique_id
string variables not allowed in varlist;
unique_id is a string variable
r(109);

xtset wanted
     panel variable:  wanted (balanced)
```